# kivy on_touch_up() fires more than one time?

Tags: python, kivy

I wonder, is there a way in kivy, where the method `on_touch_up()` fires continuously, when true? The output would look like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        print(touch.spos, "Down")

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        print(touch.spos,"Move")

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print(touch.spos,"Up")
        ### 
        #while on_touch_up():
            #print(touch.spos,"Up")
        ###

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

It prints:

```
((0.2175, 0.7716666666666667), 'Down')
((0.2175, 0.7716666666666667), 'Move')
((0.2175, 0.685), 'Move')
((0.2175, 0.5516666666666667), 'Move')
((0.2175, 0.4633333333333334), 'Move')
((0.2175, 0.44666666666666666), 'Move')
((0.2175, 0.44666666666666666), 'Up')
((0.2175, 0.43500000000000005), 'Down')
((0.23, 0.43500000000000005), 'Move')
((0.67, 0.5916666666666667), 'Up')
```

but I would like to have more "Up" in the output(like every 0.1s). I've tried `while` with `time.sleep()` but the program crushes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, are you looking to stop that from happening, or are you wanting that to happen? Please clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: 1) What do you mean for `on_touch_up()` to be 'true'? 2) Whatever you mean, you can probably achieve it using Clock.schedule_interval and some logic around when touches begin and end.

Comment: @John Anderson I edited the question. I am wanting that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this. Its not the most elegant way but it works for me.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.on_touch_up, 0.1)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        print(touch.spos, "Down")

    a = []
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        print(touch.spos,"Move")
        self.a.append(touch.spos)

    def on_touch_up(self, dt):
        if not self.a:
            pass
        else:
            print(self.a[-1], "Up")
            if len(self.a) > 2:
                del self.a[0:-2]


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to do it: add is_down property.

Example:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch, pos):
    self.is_down = True
    <your code>
def on_touch_up(self, touch, pos):
    if self.is_down:
        self.is_down = False
        <your code>
```